# Universal approximation of Gaussians

Tags: machine-learning, distributions, kernel-trick, approximation

Can gaussian kernels reproduce non continuous L2 integrable functions? ( Do non continuous L2 integrable functions lie in the RKHS constructed by a Gaussian Kernel?)

Edit:

I think my question is being misconceived. I do not intend to say that the RKHS is constructed using this argument. My question is that due to the reproducing property, every function that belongs to a Hilbert space must satisfy the reproducing property give the kernel is a reproducing kernel. Would a constant function over a compact support satisfy this for gaussian kernels?

Comment: I see you've left several comments where you say that your question has been misunderstood. The best think you can do to help people understand what you want to know, and therefore acquire relevant answers, is to [edit] your question to be clear about what you want to know.

Comment: page 14 (and a few other places) of this document may be of interest: https://www.gatsby.ucl.ac.uk/~gretton/coursefiles/lecture4_introToRKHS.pdf

Comment: see also remark 6 of this document: https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.595.9029&rep=rep1&type=pdf

Comment: This question suffers from being ill specified since "can kernels reproduce" is not a properly defined term. As one of the commenters (rightly!) points out the RKHS associated with a Gaussian kernel consists of continuous (actually they are $C^\infty$ analytic) functions and so the answer may be NO. But of course the RKHS (as a set of functions) may be embedded in an L2 space where it may be dense in the L2 norm. So the answer may be YES.

Comment: With respect to the edit: A Hilbert space may have the reproducing property but it makes no sense to talk about the reproducing property of a function in a RKHS.

Comment: @gg Why is this not a qualified question? I want to check if a function belongs to an RKHS. Does that not mean I need to check for the reproducing property associated with the kernel that constructs the RKHS and also additonally verify the finiteness of the norm?

Comment: One alternative way to phrase the *reproducing" part could be: For function $f$ constant over a compact set, does there exist a sequence $f_n$ of functions from the RKHS such that $\int \mid f_n - f\mid\rightarrow 0$ or $f_n(x)\rightarrow f(x)$ for all x. Note that this may be possible even though $f_n$ does not converge with respect to the RKHS norm and $f$ is not an element of the RKHS.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

$L_2$ integrable functions are equivalence classes of functions that can differ on subsets of measure zero. For an RKHS, you need the evaluation function at a given point $x$ to be well defined, which is not possible for such an equivalence class, since a point is of measure zero, and thus all members of the equivalence class can have different values at $x$.

---

Edit:

When I read in the question, that the OP was concerned with noncontinuous functions in a vector space complete w.r.t. the $L_2$ norm, my immediate reflex was to think of a space of equivalence classes of functions. And in such a space, evaluation at a point is in general not well defined, hence my answer.

But, as @whuber pointed out in the comments, there are $L_2$ Hilbert spaces that don't need equivalence classes to be defined properly and for which evaluation at a point is well defined. I can also think of those that, as requested by the OP, contain noncontinuous functions.

But the OP asked moreover for a **Gaussian** RKHS, i.e. one with a Gaussian kernel. And I was not able to think of a Gaussian L2 RKHS with noncontinuous functions.

So I consulted the paper:

> Cucker, Felipe, and Steve Smale. "On the mathematical foundations of learning." Bulletin of the American mathematical society 39.1 (2002): 1-49.

There, in Chapter III, Section 3, Theorem 2 is relevant to the OP's question: It essentially states that, if we have a Mercer kernel, i.e. the kernel is continuous, symmetric, and positive definite, which is the case for the Gaussian kernel, then the RKHS consists of continuous functions.

Thus, to summarize, while my first reasoning was wrong, the statement stays correct: There are no noncontinuous functions in the $L_2$ RKHS of a Gaussian kernel.

Comment: This is interesting. Does this mean that such functions that have compact support can also not be reproduced? Also does this not conflict with the fact that mixture of gaussians are dense in L2?

Comment: @Harduin A Hilbert space that has as norm the $L_2$-norm and that contains all Gaussians cannot be an RKHS: The evaluation map would not be continuous, because it would not be bounded. To see this, just take a sequence of Gaussians with constant mean, but with variance converging to zero.

Comment: Hmm. What kinds of functions does the Gaussian Kernel admit into its RKHS then?

Comment: @Harduin Please don't confuse a Gaussian function $X\to\mathbb R$ with the Gaussian kernel $k: X\times X\to \mathbb R$.

Comment: Yes, I think I jumbled them up. Thank you.

Comment: This answer works only by forcing a potentially irrelevant interpretation on the question.  "L2 integrable" literally means only that the integral of the square of the modulus of the function exists and is finite.  It does *not* refer to any kind of equivalence class.  The moral is that the answer to the question depends on what functions one includes in the space.

Comment: I think I jumbled up the question I wanted to ask and this one answers some technicalities I missed in the original question. As far as I know, the RKHS will be a subset of L2 integrable functions and not exactly all of them. @whuber Do you think my comment to the other answer holds? i.e Extrapolating off the example, say the function is uniform and bounded ( say constant k in a region from 0 to 1) , is this function still not in the rkhs?

Comment: @whuber As always, thanks for your help. I have updated my answer.

Comment: +1 Many thanks for the informative additions.

Answer (score 2):

More generally, a Hilbert space $\mathcal F$ of functions from $\mathcal X$ to $\mathbb R$ is a Reproducing Kernel Hilbert Space if and only if for all $x\in\mathcal X$, the map :
$$L_x : f\in\mathcal F\mapsto f(x)$$
is bounded. That is, if and only if there exists for all $x\in\mathcal X$ a finite $M_x$ such that
$$|f(x)|\le M_x \|f\|_{\mathcal F}\quad \forall f\in\mathcal F \tag1$$
So even if you forget for a minute that for $\mathcal F=\mathcal L^2(\mathcal X)$, $f(x)$ is not well-defined (as rightfully mentioned in @frank's answer), you can easily see that the uniform bound $(1)$ doesn't hold. For instance, let $x_0\in\mathcal X$ be arbitrary and consider the family of functions
$$f_n(x) =\begin{cases} n \text{ if } x=x_0,\\
 0 \text{ otherwise}\end{cases}$$
It is clear that all the $f_n$'s are in $\mathcal F =\mathcal L^2$ but the evaluation functional $L_{x_0}$ is unbounded by construction. Hence we can conclude that $\mathcal L^2$ **is not a RKHS for any kernel**, and in particular for the Gaussian kernel.

By a similar argument you can show that even a "well-behaved" space such as the set of all continuous functions on an interval $[a,b]$ is not an RKHS either.

Comment: Extrapolating off your example, say the function is uniform and bounded ( say constant k in a region from 0 to 1) , is this function still not in the rkhs?

Comment: What do you mean by "uniform and bounded" ? Remember that a RKHS is a family of functions, so it's not clear when speaking about a single function to ask whether it "belongs to the RKHS". Anyway, if the considered space of functions is uniformly bounded by a constant $C$, then yes, it is a RKHS for the reason stated above.

Comment: I think my question is being misconceived. I do not intend to say that the RKHS is constructed using this argument. My question is that due to the reproducing property, every function that belongs to a Hilbert space must satisfy the reproducing property give the kernel is a reproducing kernel. Would a constant function over a compact support say a box function satisfy this for gaussian kernels?